# How do you split a single pdf into several PdfFileReader objects based on page number?

Tags: python, pypdf

I need to split a PDF file into several PdfFileReader objects based on page number to extract data from a specific page using getFormTextFields(). Is there a way to do this without creating a new PDF document for each page.

Answer (score 0):

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader

pdf_document = "example.pdf"
with open(pdf_document, "rb") as filehandle:
    pdf = PdfFileReader(filehandle)
    info = pdf.getDocumentInfo()
    pages = pdf.getNumPages()

    print (info)
    print ("number of pages: %i" % pages)

    page1 = pdf.getPage(0)
    print(page1)
    print(page1.extractText())
```

Comment: Thank you, but extractText() doesn't seem to be able to pull user input form data. I would also like to keep the data as a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader

inputpdf = PdfFileReader(open("document.pdf", "rb"))

for i in range(inputpdf.numPages):
    output = PdfFileWriter()
    output.addPage(inputpdf.getPage(i))
    with open("document-page%s.pdf" % i, "wb") as outputStream:
        output.write(outputStream)
```

Comment: Thanks but I was hoping to avoid creating extra PDF files.